Generate a zip file for Maven using the Maven plugin for Gradle
I'm using the Maven plugin for gradle to publish to Sonatype's Maven repository. In the past I just used one of the gradle tasks to publish my artifacts. But Sonatype changed their system earlier this year and the Maven plugin doesn't work with their new system. The new system does however let you manually upload a zip file containing the artifacts. But I have not found a way to generate the zip file from Gradle.
Has anyone created a zip file using Gradle that contains the Maven artifacts?

You can do it using Zip task of gradle or alternatively use Buildship Plugin.

which the Maven plugin doesn't one ?
